# Laravel 4 and Bootstrap Switch

Tags: javascript, php, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-switch

I am trying to use the Bootstrap Switch (http://www.bootstrap-switch.org) with the latest version of Laravel (4.2.8) however I am new to learning this framework and PHP.

I have referenced the four required files within the head of my main index.blade.php file as shown below:

```
{{ HTML::style('public/bootstrap-switch-style/css/bootstrap-switch.css') }}
{{ HTML::style('public/bootstrap-switch-master/css/bootstrap.css') }}
{{ HTML::script('public/bootstrap-switch-master/js/jquery.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('public/bootstrap-switch-master/js/bootstrap-switch.js') }}
```

Further down the index.blade.php file I create a checkbox with a value of checked, and attempt to call the function to concert the checkbox to a toggle switch.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="my-checkbox" checked>
{{$toggle=("[name='my-checkbox']").bootstrapSwitch();}}
```

The following error appears:

Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException (E_ERROR) 
Call to undefined function bootstrapSwitch()

Underneath that error an extract of my index.blade.php file is referenced:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="my-checkbox" checked>
<?php echo $toggle=("[name='my-checkbox']").bootstrapSwitch();; ?>
```

Has anyone managed to integrate the Bootstrap Switch with Laravel previously, or is there any other way of doing this?  Ultimately this is for a staff availability website which which should toggle red for if someone is unavailable, or green for if they are available.  The status (boolean) is stored with a MySQL database.  Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really what you're trying to do:

```
<?php echo $toggle=("[name='my-checkbox']").bootstrapSwitch(); ?>
```

This is basically saying to do the following:

> Take the string `"[name='my-checkbox']"` and concatenate it with the results of calling the global function `bootstrapSwitch` and assign *those* results to the variable `$toggle` and finally `echo` the whole thing out, as a string.

The error message is correctly telling you that your PHP script is unaware of any such function.

What I think you're trying to do, *in Javascript*, is something like this:

```
$("[name='my-checkbox']").bootstrapSwitch();
```

Which is valid.  Remove the PHP tags, remove the echo and replace your current line with that and see if that works for you.  Furthermore, I would suggest going back to the [documentation](http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/), where its plainly spelled out:

1. Add your checkbox.

   `<input type="checkbox" name="my-checkbox" checked>`
2. Initialize Bootstrap Switch.

   `$("[name='my-checkbox']").bootstrapSwitch();`

Comment: Many thanks for your response.  My (failed) attempt to wrap up the initialise bootstrap switch syntax was because without it, all I see is the checkbox with $("[name='my-checkbox']").bootstrapSwitch(); directly next to it.  It's as though it does not recognise that I'm calling the function to convert the checkbox.  Many thanks.

Comment: try wrapping it inside of a script tag: `<script type="text/javascript">$("[name='my-checkbox']").bootstrapSwitch();</script>`

Comment: This hides the $("[name='my-checkbox']").bootstrapSwitch(); code however only the checkbox on its own is displayed.